# how to limit content in yii model

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way to limit n number of contents in yii model any my code is

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'editedby', 'cat_id', 'prod_id', 'parent', 'order', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'content', 'excerpt', 'date', 'url', 'posttype'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Posts::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params,'');

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'editedby' => $this->editedby,
            'cat_id' => $this->cat_id,
            'prod_id' => $this->prod_id,
            'parent' => $this->parent,
            'order' => $this->order,
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'content', $this->content])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'excerpt', $this->excerpt])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'url', $this->url])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'posttype', $this->posttype]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

it was a model to list products if the user was in free plan have to show only one product or else have to display products  based on plan count will change i have no idea that how to add the condition i need something like

```
if($user_type==1){
   $query->andFilterWhere([['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();]);
}
```

Comment: Could you use `$query->limit(1)` ?

Comment: yes just found this solution it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Raul Sauco already mentioned you could use something like that

```
$query->andFilterWhere([['id' => SORT_DESC])->limit($user_type == 1 ? 1 : 20);
```